# Multiple overlapping rectangle being drawn over an image when using cv2 to draw using mouse

Tags: python, opencv, drawing

I was trying to draw rectangles using mouse over an image, using openCV package in python. When ever I drew a rectangle, I got multiple rectangles overlapping one another, instead of a single rectangle. Like the below image

[image: the output that I got]

Here is my code. Please tell me where I went wrong and what needs to be corrected, so that I get only 1 rectangle.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing  = False
ix,iy = -1, -1
img = cv2.imread('drawing_over_image/dog.jpg')
def draw(event, x, y, flags, params):

    global ix, iy, drawing

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ix,iy = x,y
        drawing = True

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing:
            if ix < x and iy < y:
                cv2.rectangle(img=img, pt1=(ix,iy), pt2=(x,y), color=[255,0,0], thickness=1)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        cv2.rectangle(img=img, pt1=(ix,iy), pt2=(x,y), color=[255,0,0], thickness=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    while True:
        cv2.imshow(winname='image', mat=img)
        cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Its drawing multiple rectangles because you are drawing rectangles on every mouse move after user is pressing on the button. Instead you should draw whenever the event is done namely when the user release the left button. I fixed your code and add a basic ref image for you to see your rectangle when you are drawing. Hope it helps!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing  = False
ix,iy = -1, -1
img = cv2.imread('drawing_over_image/dog.jpg')
refimg = img.copy()
def draw(event, x, y, flags, params):

    global ix, iy, drawing

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ix,iy = x,y
        drawing = True
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing:
            if ix < x and iy < y:
                cv2.rectangle(img=refimg, pt1=(ix,iy), pt2=(x,y), color=[255,0,0], thickness=1)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        if ix < x and iy < y:
            cv2.rectangle(img=img, pt1=(ix,iy), pt2=(x,y), color=[255,0,0], thickness=1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    while True:
        cv2.imshow(winname='image', mat=refimg)
        cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw)
        refimg = img.copy()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering my doubt @Ahmet Pokerce. The solution seems to work but the only challenge that I am facing now is to show the rectangle being drawn as we drag the mouse ( a feature you see when drawing a rectangle in MS Paint while dragging the mouse).

Comment: Correct me if I understand your question wrong but when I tried my code it shows the rectangle that is being drawn when I drag the mouse.

Comment: this answer goes in the right direction (copying the image) but it's got **issues**: the selection rectangle *disappears* when the mouse pointer stops moving (it flickers even while moving)... at least it does for me when I run this code. I also don't understand why there's logic to prevent selection in "wrong" directions. there's no reason to disallow arbitrary start and end points. further, there's absolutely no reason to keep imshowing() anything in a loop (or setting the event handler repeatedly), while nothing happens. you *are* allowed to call imshow() from the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- use `cv.selectROI()`
- do it all by hand

### with `selectROI()`

```
rect = cv.selectROI("image", img, False)
cv.destroyWindow("image")
print(rect) # (x,y,w,h) or (0,0,0,0)
```

### by hand

- keep the original image
- while dragging, from the event handler, draw **on a copy**, imshow() that
- handle mousedown, mousemove, mouseup
- call separate completion and cancelation functions to make it neat

```
sel1 = None # first point
sel2 = None # second point

def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global sel1, sel2
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        sel1 = (x,y)
        sel2 = None

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        cancel_selection()

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if sel1 is not None:
            canvas = img.copy()
            cv2.rectangle(canvas, sel1, (x,y), color=[255,0,0], thickness=2)
            cv2.imshow("image", canvas)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        if sel1 is not None:
            sel2 = (x,y)
            selection_done(sel1, sel2)
            sel1 = sel2 = None

def cancel_selection():
    global sel1
    sel1 = None
    # restore display
    cv2.imshow("image", img)

def selection_done(pt1, pt2):
    # draw on the source image?
    cv2.rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, color=[255,255,0], thickness=2)
    cv2.imshow("image", img)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', on_mouse)

    while True:
        key = cv2.waitKey()
        if key == 27: # ESC cancels ongoing selection, or exits the window
            if sel1 is None:
                break
            else:
                cancel_selection()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```